# ListView Selection Issue in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

**What I Have**

I have a ListView showing the files on a device. I have a hidden ImageView which I want to make VISIBILE when an user clicks the "Select All" button.

**The Issue**

When the user clicks the select all button, all the items are not selected. When I scroll down, I find some items have not been selected (there image view is still INVISIBLE).

**My Code**

```
selectAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                List<Item> selectList = dir;

                for (int i = 1; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    tmpView = list.getChildAt(i);
                    select = (ImageView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.fileSelect);
                    select.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                for (int i = 1; i < selectList.size(); i++) {

                    Item o = adapter.getItem(i);
                    o.setSelected();
                }
            }
        });
```

Please suggest how to solve this problem? I know that the ListView items are reused and that is actually causing the problem, but I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you please post your adapter code ?

Comment: try to use flag and when select all button click make flag true and notify your list try to show image on list base on this flag in adapter.

Comment: Aritra @Haresh is right, you need handle that in getView method in adapter class, post that code if you had a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not correct. Cause ListView.getChildCount() only return the amount of visible list items.
I suggest this clean way: try to add selected property into your item, then you can update your view by notify dataset change. It looks like this:

```
  public class Item{
    boolean selected;
  }
```

And your adapter should like this:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     // do something to get view

     if(item.selected){
         yourImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }else{
          yourImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
 }
```

Finally, in your select all button click listener:

```
  List<Item> yourList = getYourListData();
  for (int i = 1; i < yourList.size(); i++) {

       Item o = yourList.get(i);
       o.selected = true;
  }

  // remember notify dataset changed
   adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a great solution. My code is now working perfectly.